# Как использовать словарь на Python чтобы после ввода переменная сохранялась в словарь

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

В пример приведу бота , которого пишу на питон в телеграм. Создал кнопку корзины. Хочу чтобы когда после нажатия на кнопку "выбрать" бот присылал сообщение типа "введите количество". И после этого число переносилось в словарь. Знаю что очень недоступно объяснил, но как мог так и объяснил.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, раз "как мог, так и объяснил", так "как объяснил, так и отвечаю".

Для того, что-бы добавить элемент в словарь нужно указать новый (уникальный) ключ и записываемое значение. Например:

d1["Новый ключ"]="Новое значение"